# Change how lemmas are counted in the appendix using `newcommand`

Tags: macros, theorems, counters

I use the following command to count Lemmas in my paper.

```
\newcounter{lcount}
\newcommand{\lem}[2]{\refstepcounter{lcount}\label{#1}\vspace*{0.5cm}\noindent \textbf{Lemma \thelcount.}\ \ {#2}\vspace*{0.5cm}}
```

How can I amend it so that the Lemmas in the appendix start by the letter that defines the appendix (e.g. `Lemma A1`)? I could find only threads making use of the package `chngcntr`. Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem with `\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}`? Anyway, how do you define `lcount`?

Comment: I added the defintion of `lcount`. For consistency with the other theorems in the body of the paper I was hoping to use something like `\lem{lem:1}{\textit{This Lemma is a Lemma}}`, but the counter should start from `A1` instead of continuing from the same counter in the main body.

Comment: how do you use the `\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}` command?

Comment: `\setcounter{lcount}{0}\renewcommand{\thelcount}{A\arabic{lcount}}` when you start the appendix. But, please, read a guide for better using LaTeX standard tools such as `\newtheorem`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Shall I close the thread or if you answer the question I'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you again, I'll look into the `\newtheorem` tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
\appendix
\setcounter{lcount}{0}
\renewcommand{\thelcount}{A\arabic{lcount}}
```